# Using lame as library

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, lame

I have already compile `lame` for android as static library.

How can I use lame for convert a `wav` file to `mp3`?

What I have to call? There is some tutorial of how use lame as library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see this [developer.samsung.com](http://developer.samsung.com) tutorial for porting or how we use LAME on Android with JNI

[Porting and using LAME MP3 on Android with JNI](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Porting-and-using-LAME-MP3-on-Android-with-JNI)